# Create node in graphviz using polygon as icon and text label

Tags: d3.js, graphviz, dot, d3-graphviz

Is there any way to create a node in Graphviz that looks like the below?
(Placing a hexagon and text side by side inside the node instead of just placing text inside box)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily embed nodes within other nodes, but you can insert images into nodes.  Create an image (or images) with the polygon shape(s) and insert them into an HTML-style node (record-style would probably also work).
Like so:

```
digraph i{
 {rank=same
  n1 [shape=plaintext,label=<
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="1" cellborder="0"> 
  <TR><TD FIXEDSIZE="true" height="20" width="20"><IMG  SRC="cow.png" scale="true"/></TD><TD>some text</TD></TR>
  </TABLE>
  >
  ]

  n2 [shape=plaintext,label=<
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="1" cellborder="0" >
  <TR><TD colspan="2" bgcolor="green1">Step</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD FIXEDSIZE="true" height="20" width="20"><IMG  SRC="cow.png" scale="true"/></TD><TD>some text</TD></TR>
  </TABLE>
  >
  ]
  n1 -> n2
  }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: I've tried above using an image of size 2.7 kb but I see empty space in place of the image. How do I resolve this?

Comment: can you please specify the versions of graphviz and d3 you used?

Comment: I am not using d3, I have Graphviz installed locally.  I believe d3 is Javascript-based, and while I am not familiar with its internals, my guess is that it can't read local files (the image file) for security reasons.  My Graphviz version is  5.0.1~dev.20220813.1614 (20220813.1614)